# Theming with Material UI using React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm not gettin the blue color to show up on the toolbar when I run this code. The toolbar loads with the tabs properly, but there's no theming. It's just a grey and dark greyish color. I'm expecting the lightbase theme from Material-UI@next

My main app.js file looks like this:

```js
const theme = createMuiTheme();

const render = (messages) => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Splash} />
              <Route exact path="/main" component={App} />
              <Route path="/main/:navmain" component={App} />
            </Switch>
          </MuiThemeProvider>
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </LanguageProvider>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE
  );
};
```

Then, when i navigate to /main, this is what I have:

```js
const AppWrapper = styled.div`
  max-width: calc(768px + 16px * 2);
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
  min-height: 100%;
  padding: 0 16px;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header />
        <AppWrapper>
          Below this are where the new components should render.
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/main/aboutme" component={AboutMe} />
            <Route path="/main/models" component={Models} />
            <Route path="/main/landscapes" component={Landscapes} />
          </Switch>
          <Footer />
        </AppWrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

For some reason I'm having a tough time seeing what I'm doing wrong here. I am wrapping the routes in the main switch statement with the MuiThemeProvider and expecting anything inside of that component (like the routes) to inherit the theme from Material UI.

Can anyone help me out here?

Comment: You have to apply muitheme to App component but not to the routes. You will be calling your App component somewhere in entry .js file like eg., main.js this will be ur entry file in webpack so in that file add your muitheme provider and call App component inside muithemeprovider.